# Why is it stronger statement for all positive integers $x$, but $x$ is real number in the original theorem

Tags: combinatorics

I am reading book A Walk Through Combinatorics, but I don't understand why the writer says "prove an even stronger statement".

> Corollary 5.10. For **all real numbers** $x$, and all non-negative integers $n$
> $$x^n=\sum_{k=0}^nS(n,k)(x)_k$$
> Proof: Both sides are polynomials of $x$ of degree $n$. So if we can show that they agree for more than $n$ values of $x$, we will be done. We will prove **an even stronger statement**, namely that the two sides agree for **all positive integers** $x$. 
> So let $x$ be a positive integer. Then...

Where did I get it wrong?

Update:
Another question I don't understand is how to derive "So if we can show that they agree for more than $n$ values of $x$, we will be done." from "Both sides are polynomials of $x$ of degree $n$". Why?

Comment: As the author states you only need to prove its true for more than $n$ values of $x$ but they do this by proving it's true for every positive integer (infinitely many values of $x$) which is obviously not required but may be an easier route.

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks for your answer! Now I have a new question. Literally, the reason the writer says "So if we can ..." is because "Both sides...", but how to understand the connection between them from a mathematical point of view?

Comment: If you are given $n+1$ points with distinct x-coordinates, then there is a unique polynomial of degree $n$ (or less) through them. This is because a polynomial of degree $n$ has $n+1$ coefficients. Each point gives you one linear equation, and you can uniquely solve the system of $n+1$ independent equations with $n+1$ unknowns to get the coefficients. Therefore, if two polynomials of degree $n$ agree on $n+1$ points, then they must be the same polynomial.

Comment: @LeoSHEN If we know that two $n$ degree polynomials are equal for $n+1$ values of $x$ then the interpolation polynomial of the polynomial given by subtracting the two polynomials is uniquely determined (and is equal to zero) so the two polynomials are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Assume two polynomials of degree $n$ agree at more than $n$ points.  Obviously the difference of the polynomials is also a polynomial of degree $k\le n$. By our assumption the polynomial has at least $n+1$ roots, but by fundamental theorem of algebra a non-zero polynomial of degree $k$ cannot have more than $k$ roots. It follows that the difference of polynomials is identically zero.

Answer (score 0):

If two *functions* agree for all positive integers $x$, then obviously they agree for more than $n$ real values of $x$, so in that sense they are proving a stronger statement. So it sounds like they're announcing a logical outline for the proof:

1. The two functions agree for all positive integers $x$.
2. Therefore they agree for more than $n$ real values of $x$.
3. The two functions are polynomials of degree $n$.
4. If two polynomials of degree $n$ agree for more than $n$ real values, they are identical.
5. Therefore the two functions are identical.

Note, step 4. is a general assertion about polynomials, included here to address the question in the OP's update.